# how to convert oracle function "trunc" is sql server (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server

how to convert this code (ORACLE) in sql server (MSSQL)

```
test := trunc(2021 / 100);
```

outpout is **20**

thanks for help

Comment: You don't need to truncate just `2021 / 100` because SQL Server does integer division.

Comment: @forpas no 2021/10 = 21 not 20, Olivier have good answer

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bd7c4da71ea9b1378927c66cebdf10b

Comment: You don't need floor() when you divide integers.

Comment: @forpas: integer division is the correct solution here, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in SQLServer is `FLOOR()` : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15